# How to use Bootstrap Tooltips with image links?

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling to use Bootstrap tooltips with image links. The problem is that when the `img` tag is inside the `a` tag, the tooltip doesn't display at the correct spot and seems to flicker. When inspecting the HTML, the actual `a` tag is beneath the image altogether. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paniwani/DUPyR/248/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works:

```
a { display: inline-block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DUPyR/249/